# Checking if a vector starts with a number

Tags: r, substring, quotations

I have a pretty straight forward question.  Sorry if this has already been asked somewhere, but I could not find the answer...
I want to check if genenames start with a number, and if they do start with a number, I want to add 'aaa_' to the genename. Therefor I used the following code:

```
geneName <- "2310067B10Rik"
if (is.numeric(substring(geneName, 1, 1))) {
  geneName <<- paste("aaaa_", geneName, sep="")
}
```

What I want to get back is aaaa_2310067B10Rik.  However, is.numeric returns a FALSE, because the substring gives "2" in quotations as a character. I've also tries to use noquote(), but that didnt work, and as.numeric() around the substring, but then it also applies the if code to genes that don't start with a number. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: explore the result of `is.na(as.numeric(substring(geneName, 1, 1)))` or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions and use `grepl()`, i.e. `grepl("^\\d", geneName)`

Comment: `<<-` is dangerous! `library("fortunes"); fortune(174)` read https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf Circle 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
geneName <- c("2310067B10Rik", "foo") 

ifelse(substring(geneName, 1,1) %in% c(0:9), paste0("aaaa_", geneName), geneName)

[1] "aaaa_2310067B10Rik" "foo"
```

Or based on above comment, you could replace `substring(geneName, 1,1) %in% c(0:9)` by `grepl("^\\d", geneName)`

Comment: Your welcome. Please consider to upvote or accept the answer if it was helpful to you. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution with regex ([Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions) ):

```
geneName <- c("2310067B10Rik", "Z310067B10Rik")
sub("^(\\d)", "aaa_\\1", geneName)
```

or as PERL-flavoured variant (thx to @snoram):

```
sub("^(?=\\d)", "aaa_", geneName, perl = TRUE)
```

Comment: Similarly flavoured alternative `sub("^(?=\\d)", "aaa_", geneName, perl = TRUE)`. +1 btw.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `replace()` function:

```
start_nr <- grep("^\\d", geneName)
replace(geneName, start_nr, paste0("aaaa_", geneName[start_nr]))
[1] "aaaa_2310067B10Rik" "foo"                "aaaa_9bar"
```

Where:

```
geneName <- c("2310067B10Rik", "foo", "9bar")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `regex`:

You can first check the first character of your `geneName` and if it is digit then you can append as follow:

```
geneName <- "2310067B10Rik"
ifelse(grepl("^[0-9]*$", substring(geneName, 1,1)),paste("aaaa",geneName,sep="_"),)
```

Output:

```
[1] "aaaa_2310067B10Rik"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 geneName=function(x){
   if( grepl("^[0-9]",x) ){
     as.character(glue::glue('aaaa_{x}'))
   }else{x}
 }
> geneName("2310067B10Rik")
[1] "aaaa_2310067B10Rik"
> geneName("sdsad")
[1] "sdsad"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Nic3500  totaly agree